# Renaming module in maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have below multi module maven project.

```
Parent
      pom.xml
      artifactId1
            pom.xml
      artifactId2
            pom.xml
```

now i want to rename `artifactId2`. how can i do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686611/maven-rename-module-name

Comment: Other than just changing the name of the artifactId2 directory and changeing thing the <module> tag to match in Parent/pom.xml?

Answer (score 3):

It's a two step procedure:

1) Rename the project in Eclipse (F2 or Refactor -> Rename)

2) Update the artifactId in the parent pom.xml and in the artifactId2 pom.xml

Comment: make sure the folder name of the project renamed also